# why following script is failing?

Tags: shell-script, sh

```
#!/bin/sh
declare -a LIST= ('a' 'b' 'c' )
```

is failing on Ubuntu on which `/bin/sh` is softlink to `/bin/dash`

How can I declare list which will be supportable on all kind of shell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. That's why the first line (which should have a leading `#`, which would have appeared if you had written the text as code) allows you to specify the shell to which it is relevant. In particular, `csh` is very different from Bourne (sh), Korn (ksh) and Bourne-again (bash).

However, sh/ksh/bash have similar syntax for common features, so `sh` scripts should run on ksh/bash. `dash` seems to be about equivalent to Bourne, but arrays are a bash/ksh extension not present in sh/dash.

Just change your first line to `#!/bin/bash` and you won't have a problem.

There is plenty of compatibility information at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh, with a detailed list of differences.

Comment: ok your solution is working fine ,but how to declare a list which /bin/dash supports ?

Comment: These are discussed in detail in item 23 in my link.

Comment: #!/bin/sh
local LIST=\('a' 'b' 'c'\)

Comment: above program giving error as ./filename.sh: 2: local: not in a function

Comment: could you please give one example ?

Comment: I've tried to work out an example, but I couldn't get any sort of array handling to work. I don't understand why you are trying to avoid the shell with the features you need. Since I discovered ksh/bash I have never gone back to using Bourne. (I have a hammer and a spanner in my tool-kit, and I could knock in nails with the spanner, but I never do - so use the right tool for the job.)

Comment: you are right but it should work as we use /bin/sh as first statement in shell and if it is softlink to /bin/dash then it should not create problem for customers

Comment: I don't think that the link to `dash` should cause problems in itself, as it is more or less compatible with Bourne, but neither seems to offer much in the way of array handling. `bash` is pretty much universal on Linux systems, but if you need something to run on other Unix systems, then use `ksh`: this is installed by default on Ubuntu, though I can't speak for other distributions. If it's missing, you may get away with linking it to `bash`. The answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112031/difference-between-korn-and-bash-shell may help.